# Using a separate register to store return address?

Tags: security, assembly, hardware, exploit

I'm reading about how exploits work, and it seems like a lot of them operate by overwriting the return address on the stack. There's been a lot of effort put into making this more difficult (stack canaries, ASLR, DEP, etc), but it seems to me that it would be easier for hardware producers to add a register, only accessible by the call and ret instructions, that would hold the return address. This way, the return address could not be overwritten by a buffer overflow by definition. Because call and ret are still present and still operate as in today's CPUs (the only difference is where they store the return address), it would seem to me that there wouldn't be too many issues with compatibility. And since you're using a register instead of RAM to access the address, the performance impact would probably be positive (albeit insignificant).

Intel apparently has space to allocate more registers for security purposes, since MPX is being implemented despite needing two extra registers. So why don't they add a special register to store the return address?

Comment: That's not a totally unsound idea, I've read about it somewhere (unfortunately I don't remember where). The elephant in the room is that we need a stack structure to allow arbitrarily nested function calls. A separate call/ret stack (that's the idea I was referring previously) seems more robust. Compatibility issues are inevitable, some tools rely on how the stack is filled during function calls but I believe we can afford (yet another) transition period.

Comment: So how would you resolved nested calls? (except storing the value into memory, which can be then manipulated by the code any way)

Comment: The performance benefit of having an on-chip return address can be achieved by a [return address cache](https://priorart.ip.com/IPCOM/000108056) to predict the result of the RET instruction.

Answer (score 2):

This already kinda exists. I know three architectures and one language with features like that:

- SPARC has something called [*register windows*](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/sparcstack.html) where the basically the CPU saves and restores registers one function call/return. By convention, the return address is stored in register `o7` on function call, which is then rotated to `i7` when the callee establishes his stack frame. When the callee calls another function, this address is rotated away into the internal register stack, untouchable by dangerous code.
- Knuth's MMIX has a similar design but the return address is stored directly into the mostly inaccessible register stack on function call, so pretty much what you want.
- ARM and ARM64 just have a *link register.* On function call, the return address is stored in the link register, a function return is just an indirect jump to the address in the link register. This doesn't really do what you want as the content of the link register must be stored in the stack in nested function calls, defeating its extra security in anything but leaf functions (i.e. functions that call no other functions).
- The Forth programming language has by design one stack for values and a separate stack for return addresses. Both stacks can be manipulated freely by programs, though you need to be careful when manipulating the return stack. In practice, this is implemented by using one of the architecture's registers for the return stack and one for the data stack. This also solves the problem you mentioned but a sufficiently clever programmer could still mess up by allowing wrong input to smash the return stack.

Comment: Register window are just a hardware feature that gets in the way of hardware pipelining as well as better compiler optimization... they aren't the feature you are looking for. They are a flaw that Sparc has to live with.

Comment: @cb88 How do they hinder pipelining?

Comment: Originally they were put in because compilers were too dumb to schedule the register loads/stores instructions well, however that has changed and register windows are actually slower and less power efficient than a good compiler... switching register windows in hardware also makes the pipelines much more complex and increases the chances of stalls and or bubbles depending on how it's implemented... no other processors do them these days for good reason. And Sparc only does it because they have to because it's in the Spec.

Comment: Because it's more hardware and software that you have to figure out how to split between pipelines stages if you can at all. The register windows are also implemented in the supervisor software as well (since that handles paging in and out).  MIPS on the other hand has just a flat register file and cache.... vastly simpler and the cache and modern compilers are better about doing what the register windows try to accomplish on their own.